# Session State Issue

Tags: iphone, asp.net

When visiting a page, I am storing a value in session state. When I click back on the browser, the value in session reverts to its original value. Why does this happen? I am not resetting  the value when i go back.

This happens on iPhone and iPad - all other browsers do NOT roll back the session state value.

Thanks in advance.

I am using this javascript code (code in both pages is identical):

```
function pageLoad() {
    // Get the current url path
    var url = document.URL;

    PageMethods.IsNavigatingBackward(url, handleCallback);
}

function handleCallback(isBackward) {
    if (isBackward) {
        // Go back to previous page
        history.back();
    }
    else {
        // Set the current url in the session
        var url = document.URL;

        PageMethods.SetCurrentPage(url, getLocation);
    }
}
```

And the code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool IsNavigatingBackward(Uri url)
{
    string currentPath = url.LocalPath;
    string lastPath = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["LastPage"];
    bool isBackward = false;

    NavigationList table = NavigationList.GetInstance();

    if (table.IsBackwardNavigation(currentPath, lastPath))
    {
        isBackward = true;
    }

    return isBackward;
}

[WebMethod]
public static void SetCurrentPage(Uri url)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["LastPage"] = url.LocalPath;
}
```

Comment: Give us some code, are you sure the variable is not stored in the viewstate?

Comment: <body onload="pageLoad">

Answer (score 1):

You will only see the new session state value if the browser is:

- Accepting cookies
- Not showing you the cached original page

If both are these are true and assuming you're not reverting the value somewhere on the second page load, you will see the session state.

It would appear iPhone and iPad are not doing this.

Comment: How can I force a reload of the page when going back?

Comment: You can't, but you can [request the browser not to cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9s3a17d(v=VS.100).aspx) so will be forced to reload each time.

Comment: `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);` on your page should do the trick

Comment: I put that into Page_Load in code behind and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what's going on.  More than likely, the page is not being re-downloaded (and thus the session is not actually being set to anything).  it's just using the previously cached downloaded page.

Comment: In this case, the method is a static function called from javascript onLoad - PageMethods.SetCurrentPage(url);. I have been able to set a break point on the statement and step through it.

Comment: That's important information, and completely changes the context of the problem.  Now you're dealing with static issues.  Without seeing code, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the following instead:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```